# Cannot convert zip file (either event iam attached). with Autodesk Forge API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am testing with reference url ( https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-zip-to-stl/ )

There are no problem task1(Obtain an Access Token) and task2(Upload Source File to OSS).

### Task2 result is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL1sd.png)

Errors are occuring in Task3 (Translate Source File)

### My request is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgZQM.png)

---

### Response

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2L9x.png)

### When I check the status using API, an error occurs
My Request is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDv1C.png)

### Response ( Error occur )

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nlo5.png)

I want to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the IAM file directly in the root of the ZIP file? It must not be in any subfolder.

Comment: If the ZIP file is structured correctly and you're still having issues, can you share the file file with us? If it's confidential, feel free to share it with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (do) com`.

Comment: And a small note (although probably not related to the issue discussed here): trailing "=" characters should always be removed from the URNs when communicating with the Model Derivative service.

Comment: To. Petr Broz.. test file was downloaded from ( https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-tutorial-postman/tree/master/ModelDerivative_02/tutorial_data )

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps try submitting a Model Derivative job for the same file in the past? The manifest says that it failed generating an *SVF* output while now you are trying to generate an *STL* output. Note that when a job was already submitted for a specific URN (no matter whether it succeeded or failed), submitting another job won't work unless you force it. You can either:

- delete the existing derivatives using the [DELETE :urn/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-DELETE/) endpoint and then submit your job for the STL file again, or
- submit the job with the [x-ads-force: true](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#headers) header to force the translation to restart

Btw. I just tried processing the same zip file using Postman, and got a successful response:
[image]